# Concepts on fork() system call

Tags: unix, operating-system, printf, fork

If the call to fork() is executed successfully, Unix will
make two identical copies of address spaces, one for the parent and the other for the child.
Both processes will start their execution at the next statement following the fork() call.[Ref:http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/create.html].

So,if I execute the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello\n");
    fork();
    printf("World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I think it will print

```
Hello
World
World
```

But when I run the program it prints

```
Hello
World
Hello
World
```

Please explain where am I lacking in concept?

Comment: Strange,I am getting expected output.
Hello
World
World

Comment: I think if you use printf() you can't have 'Hello World World' o/p.correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You will have "Hello World World" as output,I simply copied and compiled the code,and got the same and this is what I expected.

Comment: check these too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978568/why-strange-behavior-of-fork-system-call
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255388/fork-behavior-in-linux

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/62414/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2):

This is about buffering.  When you print "hello" it doesn't go to output immediately.  Instead, it goes to a buffer.  It's still there during the fork, so, when each task terminates and flushes its buffer, there are two copies to send to output.

To counter this, you could specify unbuffered I/O or call `fflush` before the fork to flush the buffer.

Comment: @Gilles removed my mention of using terminal input to flush terminal output.  I still think it's worth mentioning.  `fflush` works as well, of course.  It's just fancier.

Comment: I don't see what makes it “fancier”. `fflush` has the advantage of being simpler and of always working. Using terminal input only works if you're reading terminal input, which is often not the case.

Comment: @Gilles, my idea is that OP is a beginner, so not acquainted with a wide spectrum of system calls.  I want to reply in simple terms so that he gets the idea without having to delve into new documentation.  Terminal I/O is where most people start out.